# Efficient way of changing the query (a way to avoid unions)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, union

I have two stored procedures and one function. I need to do some calculations after getting the price from function. I am using UNION to concatenate the query at the end, but it's very slow.

```
PROCEDURE STORED_PROC1
(
    custId IN varchar2,
    param2 IN varchar2,
    param3      IN DATE,
    param4      IN DATE,
    ret_cd OUT VARCHAR2,
    results out t_cursor
) as
   sql_str VARCHAR2(10000);
   custCursor t_cursor;
   BEGIN
    sql_str := 'select qry.col1,qry.col2,qry.col3,qry.col4,qry.col5,qry.col6, qry.price, **qry.price*col5**
                    (select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, getPrice(col1,col2,col3,col4) as price from tableA, tableB where ....) qry'; 
    open results for sql_str;
   END STORED_PROC1;
   
FUNCTION getPrice ( col1 varchar2, col2 varchar2, col3 varchar2, col4 DATE) RETURN number AS total number;
    sql_str VARCHAR2(10000);
    BEGIN
      select price into total from tableB where ......
      return total;
    end;
    
PROCEDURE STORED_PROC2
(
    custId IN varchar2,
    param2 IN varchar2,
    param3      IN DATE,
    param4      IN DATE,
    custIds in varchar2;
    ret_cd OUT VARCHAR2,
    results out t_cursor
) as
  sql_str VARCHAR2(10000);
 
 
 loop 
 for each custId ...
    call STORED_PROC1
    create a dynamic sql.
 end loop.

execute the dynamic sql at the end. 

dynamic SQL at the end will be like this:

select qry.col1,qry.col2,qry.col3,qry.col4,qry.col5,qry.col6, qry.price, **qry.price*col5** from
                    (select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, getPrice(col1,col2,col3,col4) as price from tableA, tableB) qry
                    
UNION
select qry.col1,qry.col2,qry.col3,qry.col4,qry.col5,qry.col6, qry.price, **qry*price*col5** from
                    (select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, getPrice(col1,col2,col3,col4) as price from tableA, tableB) qry
                    
 UNION
 ............
  
  END STORED_PROC2;

So this query with UNION is working, but is very slow as the range expands. wanted to see if there is a better way to do this.
```

I call a stored procedure STORED_PROC1 with param1,param2,param3 and param4.
This STORED_PROC1 calls getPrice with the values in each row.
but custIds is a concatenation of individual custId, separated by commas.
custIds = id1,id2,id3. So I need to call this STORED_PROC1 for each of
custId.

Comment: If the subqueries do not return duplicate data which must be filtered out I suggest that you use UNION ALL instead of UNION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe you don't have to do it as you described. Why wouldn't you calculate price immediately, within `STORED_PROC1`? Something like this:

```
procedure stored_proc1 (param1,...,
                        results out t_cursor
                       )
is
begin
  open results for
    select col1, 
           col2, 
           ..., 
           getPrice(col1, col2, ...) as price         --> call the function here
    from tableA;
end;
```

Comment: I was not able to frame my question properly. But I updated it now.